# How to take Image with webservice?

Tags: react-native

I have an online database and I put images there.
I use fetch to call webservice but it gives me an error because of images. how to handle this?

```
 fetch('url', {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: new Headers({
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Content-Type': 'application/json', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
       }),
      })
      .then((response) => { 
         console.log(response);
        });
```

this is my fetch. As I said When call web service it gives me an error because of not fetching images

*I serializer in webservice like this :*

```
public class Data
    {
        public string Ref { get; set; }

        public int CharacterID { get; set; }
        public string CharacterName { get; set; }
        public string Regions { get; set; }
        public string Rarity { get; set; }
        public char Role { get; set; }
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public int Power { get; set; }
        public string Tag1 { get; set; }
        public string Tag2 { get; set; }
        public string Tag3 { get; set; }
        public string RareMaterial { get; set; }
        public string EpicMaterial { get; set; }
        public string UniqueMaterial { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }


        [JsonConverter(typeof(ImageConverter))]
        public Image Images { get; set; }

    }

    public class ImageConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var base64 = (string)reader.Value;
            // convert base64 to byte array, put that into memory stream and feed to image
            return Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64)));
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var image = (Image)value;
            // save to memory stream in original format
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
            // write byte array, will be converted to base64 by JSON.NET
            writer.WriteValue(imageBytes);
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(Image);
        }
    }
```

*how to deserialize this in react-native ?*

Comment: how you store your image on API? a path or format like base64

Comment: Can you post the exact error you have ?

Comment: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Root element is missing.</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"

Comment: SOAP returns a xml. If you want to return a json with SOAP you must added as a CDATA in the response xml. What framework/library are you using in the server side ?

Comment: newtonSoft. By the way, How tO add CDATA ?

Comment: Pure Speculation: I think there is something wrong with your POST parameters. it seems like your request doesn't even gets through.

Comment: I solved problem. Problem was on url :) thx for helping